# Meaning of leaf type in Julia

Tags: types, julia

It seems that all concrete types in Julia are leaf types, but the reverse is not true. For example, `Type{Int64}` is a leaf type but it is not concrete:

```
julia> Type{Int64}.abstract
true

julia> Type{Int64}.isleaftype
true
```

My understanding is that this makes sense, because there are no values that have type `Type{Int64}`. The type `Int64` has concrete type `DataType`. However, because `Type{Int64}` has no nontrivial subtypes, it is considered a leaf type.

However, the documentation of `isleaftype` is a little confusing:

```
  isleaftype(T)

  Determine whether T is a concrete type that can have instances, meaning its
  only subtypes are itself and Union{} (but T itself is not Union{}).
```

`Type{Int64}` cannot have instances, so the first sentence suggests that it is not a leaf type. However, it is indeed true that its only subtypes are itself and `Union{}`, so the second sentence suggests that it is.

Is the documentation conflating leaf types and concrete types, and if so, which meaning is correct?

Comment: Good question. Just to clarify a point: While there's no `x` for which (1) `typeof(x) == Type{Int}`, there is for which (2) `x::Type{Int}` (i.e. `x == Int`). Does (1) define an "instance"/"concrete type" pair? `Type` does have subtypes: `DataType`, `TypeConstructor` and `TypeUnion`. Also, both `DataType::Type` and `Type::DataType` are valid – treating types as values leads to all kinds of weirdness.

Comment: It is not straightforward. There's a relevant discussion here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17086

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right; the part about having instances was probably added to give a more intuitive sense of which types these are, but is not strictly correct (if having instances is defined as `typeof(x) === T`).

The `.abstract` field is a property of the type family (`Type`) that basically tells you whether the type was declared with `abstract` (as opposed to `type` or `immutable` or `bitstype`). This just tells you whether some members of the family can have declared subtypes, and so is not directly related to being a leaf type or concrete type. As you observe, `Type{Int}.abstract` is true, but an example that goes the other way is that `Complex.abstract` is false, even though `Complex` by itself is neither leaf nor concrete since since the parameter is unspecified.